# passing javascript array to php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying learn how to pass array to php, the alert('success') does show but I don't think the value does pass to php because the alert inside the php does not show.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function submit(){
        var TableData = {"table1":"sample1","table2":"sample2","table3":"sample3"};
        var Data = JSON.stringify(TableData);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getInfo.php",
          data: {pTableData : Data},
          success: function(){
            alert('Success');
          }//success
        });
    }//submit();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button type = "button" onclick = "submit();">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
  $table = json_decode($_POST['pTableData']);
  $msg = $table['table1'];
  echo '<script>alert("';
  echo $msg;
  echo '");</script>';
?>
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Do you have access to a PHP debugger?

Comment: i dont have PHP debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve your response into success function. Also in php you have to pass `$table = json_decode($_POST['pTableData'], true);` otherwise it return as object not array

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function submit(){
        var TableData = {"table1":"sample1","table2":"sample2","table3":"sample3"};
        var Data = JSON.stringify(TableData);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get_info.php",
          data: {pTableData : Data},
          success: function(result){ //retrieve data
            alert('Success');
            alert(result); //alert it
          }//success
        });
    }//submit();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button type = "button" onClick = "submit();">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
  $table = json_decode($_POST['pTableData'],true);
  $msg = $table['table1'];  
  echo $msg;  
?>
```

Comment: ahhh, Thank You very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understood, you want your PHP script (on a back-end) to show you an alert. So, it is impossible, because `alert()` - is a JavaScript method, it is to say that it should be evaluated inside of a user's browser you to see an alert caused by your PHP script. Moreover, do not confuse the `back-end` and `front-end` definitions. As I already said, PHP - is a back-end language, so it **cannot** be used to interact with an end-user directly. There are JavaScript and HTML languages (front-end) for such a need.

Try modifying your JavaScript code to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getInfo.php",
    data: {pTableData : Data},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append(data);
    } //now it will insert the code your PHP script produced on a back-end 
      //onto the page's body, so, you are gonna see an alert only if the PHP 
      //have actually echoed a correct HTML back to the JavaScript on that context
});
```

You may also be interested in a function like `console.log()` (*it's not a JavaScript standard - it's implemention depends on a browser you are to use; it works in [Webkit, Gecko and in latest Microsoft browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=console.log). By the way, it is to say that is **should not** be used in deployed projects*). So, you can modify your `success` method to something like `console.log(data);`. When the ajax request is done, open the developer console (Ctrl+Shift+C by default in most WebKit browsers) and see what happens.